# Magento 1.7: toolbar/pager.phtml: getShowAmounts/getShowPerPage-> Where can I configure this?

Tags: configuration, toolbar, magento-1.7, backend

After updating from Magento CE 1.4.2.0 to CE 1.7.0.2 my toolbar was broken.

But I've fixed it, but I think in wrong way.

In file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/pager.phtml

we have 3 if/endif but I don't find where I can configure this:

```
<?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>

<?php if($this->getShowPerPage()): ?>

<?php if($this->getShowAmounts()): ?>
```

I've commented out, so I can use it.

where I can set to use the Container?

I wonder why it doesn't work, my getShowPerPage and getShowAmounts,
because I set it in Admin Backend->System-Config->Catalog->Shop!

Why getShowPerPage & getShowAmounts didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout  in file \app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Pager.php for methods

```
getShowPerPage() 

getShowAmounts()
```

and debug, it should be here...